# Custom .desktop file not showing in Nautilus "Open With" menu

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, nautilus

I want to be able to double click on a Python script (or SH script) inside Nautilus and then it run. So I made a custom desktop file, contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=ExecTxt
Exec=run-txtexe %f
Icon=application-x-executable
MimeType=text/x-python;application/x-shellscript;
NoDisplay=true
Comment=Runs executable text files
Terminal=false
Categories=System;Launchers;
```

I put this in a file named `run-txtexe.desktop` under `~/.local/share/applications`.

I go to Nautilus, right-click on a Python script (text/x-python) and mouse over the "Open With " menu. Not there. I click on "Other Application...". Not there. I then click "Show other applications". Not there either!

Is this a bug or am I just doing something wrong?

I am running:

```
Fedora 19
Nautilus 3.8.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new... 'feature' of Nautilus 3.8, it ignores .desktop files that have NoDisplay=true

Possible workaround: replace NoDisplay=true with NotShowIn=NAME-OF-YOUR-DESKTOP-ENVIRONMENT

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1001988

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1238634